# PHP - array_chunk - can't adapt it to work properly

Tags: php

Hello everybody I'm new in the php world still learning, and I'm completely lost. I've tried everything and read a lot of blogs but nothing helps me to figure out how to do it.
I have this code (below) which works perfectly.. it's dividing a long list in blocks of 5 elements, thanks to `<ul>` & `<li>`'s.

```
<?php
$values = range(1, 31);
$rows = array_chunk($values, 5);


foreach ($rows as $row) {
    print "<ul>";
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        print "<li>" . $value . "</li>";
    }
    print "</ul>";
}
?>
```

But When I try to merge it together with my other code (below), it stops to work. It only displays the `<ul>`'s and no data is putted in `<li>`'s which don't even display.

```
<?php 
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
        ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'manufacturer');
        $attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
        $manufacturers = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
?>


<ul> 
<?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="/manufacturer/<?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?>">
            <?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This is one of the variants I've tried (the one that doesn't show me a 500 error)

```
<?php
$rows = array_chunk($manufacturers, 5);


foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($row as $manufacturer) {
        echo "<li>"  ?> 
                <a href="/manufacturer/<?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?></a>
<?php   echo "</li>"; ?>
<?php    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

I know probably what I'm doing is completely wrong, but as I said I'm new still learning (I have a long way to go, I know.)

Any help will be more than appreciate. Thank you in advance!

EDITS:
    Array ( [value] => 15 [label] => Jordan )
    Array ( [value] => 19 [label] => Maison Scotch )
    Array ( [value] => 5 [label] => Museum )
    Array ( [value] => 17 [label] => Nike )
    Array ( [value] => 16 [label] => Nike Basket )
    Array ( [value] => 11 [label] => On Tour )
    Array ( [value] => 7 [label] => PeB )
    Array ( [value] => 14 [label] => Penfiled )
    Array ( [value] => 4 [label] => President's )
    Array ( [value] => 23 [label] => Scotch & Soda )
    Array ( [value] => 12 [label] => Solovair )
    Array ( [value] => 13 [label] => Supra )
    Array ( [value] => 20 [label] => Vans )
    Array ( [value] => 18 [label] => Wood Wood )

Comment: What is in the `$manufacturer` variable?  Please put this line just after your `foreach` loop: `print_r($manufacturer);`.  Thanks.

Comment: Learn to monitor your servers log files, especially the error log file. You gain valuable hints on what is wrong.

Comment: `$manufacturer` With the second script I'm taking all the "manufacturers" from Magento and what I have is a long list, but I need to divide them in columns of 5. 

P.s: I updated the original post with the results of print_r();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix your variables. Probably you want something like this:

```
<?php
$rows = array_chunk($manufacturers, 5);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($row as $manufacturer) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="/manufacturer/<?php echo $manufacturer['label']; ?>">
                this is a link
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Note how the variables are cascaded in the two foreach loops.

Comment: omg, arkascha thank you sooo much for your time and for your help! Really appreciate that. Thank you!